# Error: Getter not found: 'widget'. widget.icon

Tags: android, flutter, widget

I am creating a card component that contains icons and text as a children's widget.
I initialize these icons and wanted to make use of them inside its children widget but it's giving errors
[image]

The error is indicated above the image.
It happened on widget.icon, widget.title, and it's also happened if I used it on widget.subtitle. Below is the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CardsParent extends StatefulWidget {
 const CardsParent({
   Key key,
   @required this.size,
   this.icon,
   this.title,
   this.subtitle,
 }) : super(key: key);

 final Size size;
 final IconData icon;
 final String title;
 final String subtitle;

 @override
 _CardsParentState createState() => _CardsParentState();
}

class _CardsParentState extends State<CardsParent> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     width: 140,
     height: 100,
     child: Card(
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
       ),
       color: Colors.white,
       elevation: 10,
       child: Column(
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
         children: <Widget>[
           const ListTile(
             leading: Icon(
               widget.icon,
               size: 50,
               color: kOrangeColor,
             ),
             title: Text('Temp',
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: kOrangeColor)),
             subtitle: Text('33C', style: TextStyle(color: kOrangeColor)),
           ),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

Am I doing something wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to remove the `const` from your ListTile.

Comment: I am facing another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67793409/flutter-route-not-responding-onclick