# Flutter Route Not Responding onClick

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-routes

I have created a card component that contains icons, text and pressn as parameters inside card component. The pressn represents route. All other widgets are working except pressn widget which represents the route widget.

Am I suppose to assign any unClick or tab function to pressn?

Below is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:api_example_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class CardsParent extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardsParent({
    Key key,
    @required this.size,
    this.icon,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.pressn,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final GestureTapCallback pressn;

  @override
  _CardsParentState createState() => _CardsParentState();
}

class _CardsParentState extends State<CardsParent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 140,
      height: 100,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 10,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(
                widget.icon,
                size: 50,
                color: kOrangeColor,
              ),
              title: Text(widget.title,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: kOrangeColor)),
              subtitle: Text(widget.subtitle,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, color: kOrangeColor)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is where I want to make use of the code, where I passed pressn to represent the Navigator.

```
 Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.temperatureHigh,
                  title: 'Tem',
                  subtitle: '33C',
                  pressn: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => TemSensorScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                CardsParent(
                  size: size,
                  title: 'Hum ',
                  subtitle: '75%',
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.cloudShowersHeavy,
                 pressn: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => HumSensorScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not using the `pressn` anywhere from your `CardsParent`

Comment: I used it. please, check:   ` press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  CupertinoPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SensorScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },`

Comment: Here's how I have destructured the code [1]: ibb.co/Jt0cmxn 
Where I am using it: ibb.co/FHCY9Tx

Comment: After these changes are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes. Please, go through my code here: https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system. This is where I am doing all the functions: https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system/blob/main/lib/LandingScreen/components/Cards.dart. This is where I am using it:   https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system/blob/main/lib/LandingScreen/components/body.dart.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- In the current scenario, when you call onTap it will return null value always and your GestureDetector won't respond to touches. So remove the following code:

```dart
get onTap => null; // Remove this
```

- You need to pass widget.onTap to your gesture detector (not onTap):

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.onTap, // Change is here
      child: Container(
          // Remaining Code
      ),
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use GestureDetector.

```
return GestureDetector(
  onTap: pressn,
  child: Container(
    width: 140,
    height: 100,
    child: Card(),
  ),
)
```

Comment: It still not working after adding. my final code

Comment: It still not working.  `class _CardsParentState extends State<CardsParent> {
  get pressn => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: pressn,
      child: Container(
        width: 140,
        height: 100,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),),`}

Comment: Here's how I have destructured the code

   [1]: https://ibb.co/Jt0cmxn

Comment: Yes. Please, go through my code here: https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system. This is where I am doing all the functions: https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system/blob/main/lib/LandingScreen/components/Cards.dart. This is where I am using it:   https://github.com/IsoftTech/smart-irrigation-system/blob/main/lib/LandingScreen/components/body.dart.